# How to remove/disable paragraph indentation inside a forest node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, indentation, forest

I tried all the tricks I know about. `\usepackage{parskip}` and `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` and `\noindent` but none are working inside a forest node. Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[   
Write the ode as 
{\begin{align*}
y'+p(x)y&=q(x)\\
        &=f(x,y)
\end{align*}
}
This is only possible if ode is linear in {$y$}
,text width=4cm
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried adding `\noident` inside the node, but it had no effect

```
\begin{forest}
[   
\noindent
Write the ode as 
{\begin{align*}
y'+p(x)y&=q(x)\\
        &=f(x,y)
\end{align*}
}
This is only possible if ode is linear in {$y$}
,text width=4cm
]
\end{forest}
```

What Am I doing wrong and how to remove this extra horizontal space after the `align*` environment?

TL 2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not an indent, it's an inter-word space that you are adding in the source file

[image]

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[   
Write the ode as 
{\begin{align*}
y'+p(x)y&=q(x)\\
        &=f(x,y)
\end{align*}
}%%%%%
This is only possible if ode is linear in {$y$}
,text width=4cm
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```